# Check file exists on different servers remotely

Tags: java, python, linux

I need to check the existence of some files on different servers remotely. The servers are in Linux and AIX.

I tried python telnet and the linux shell behave differently at login so I need to use different code for different OS to recognize the prompt symbol so that I could issue command via telnet:

Linux:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(self.mHost)
tn.read_until(b"login: ")
tn.write(self.mUsername.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
tn.write(self.mPassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
(tn.read_until(b"$")).decode('ascii')
```

AIX:

```
tn2 = telnetlib.Telnet(self.mHost)
tn2.read_until(b"login: ")
tn2.write(self.mUsername.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
tn2.read_until(b"Password: ")
tn2.write(self.mPassword.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
(tn2.read_until(b">")).decode('ascii')
```

After connection succesful, I used a simple 'ls' command to check with the files.

```
ls -ltr  | awk -F" " '{print $5 "|" $6 "-" $7 "-" $8 "|" $9}' | tail -n 20
```

However bash shell and ksh shell may behave differently in some commands so I need to a once-write-run-everywhere solution.

Available choice: Java 6, Python 3.0

Comment: Can you please tell which version of the java you can use?

Comment: You forgot to put question/problem you have into the post.

Comment: Why must you use telnet? Don't both servers have an SSH daemon running?

Answer (score 0):

Asusming both servers are UNIX/Linux based and have an SSH Daemon running you could use (Fabric)[http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/contrib/files.html#fabric.contrib.files.exists}'s `fabric.contrib.exists()` function call.

**Interactive Example:**

```
from fabric.api import execute
from fabric.contrib.files import exists

>>> execute(exists, "data.csv", hosts=["localhost"])
[localhost] Executing task 'exists'
{'localhost': True}
```

Comment: I assume the developer haven't test on AIX or other similar korn shell based OS?

Comment: Not sure; but as it's POSIX it *should* work :) I'd just give it a try -- Python is cross platform so in *theory* it should "just work" :)